# NaN values in htmlUnit getPage

Tags: javascript, svg, htmlunit, shieldui

I'm trying to get a page html using htmlUnit library. I think some javascript are not executed properly, since I get Nan in some attribute values.
I use this code for retrieving the page:

```
webClient = new WebClient();
final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(TEST_WEB_PAGE);
```

here is a fragment from the the output page.asXml() instruction (the anomaly happens in many tags):

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="1256" height="362">
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="shielddx">
            <rect rx="0" ry="0" fill="none" x="0" y="0" width="9999" height="362" stroke-width="0"/>
        </clipPath>
        <clipPath id="shielddy">
            <rect fill="none" x="0" y="0" width="NaN" height="NaN"/>
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
    ...
```

If I open TEST_WEB_PAGE in a browser and I open the dev panel attributes are correctly filled up.

TEST_WEB_PAGE has been created using Apache wiket and shieldUi

Can anyone help me?

Laura

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see, there may be an issue with the way the page is parsed, which I attribute to the htmlUnit library that you are using, rather than the ShieldUI components, which are standard. You can check the htmlUnit support page and determine whether what you are trying to achieve is a supported scenario.